# Grails disallow normal create

Tags: grails

Grails noob here. I am build a simple grails app where I have the default create/ edit / list / show pages for a Product domain object. I also have the `ProductController`. The create method by default does this:

```
def create() {
    [productInstance: new Product(params)]
}
```

My understanding is this will take me to the create page. And there will be nothing in the params object so everything will be blank.

I want to change the behaviour so that the when the `create()` method is invoked, a pop up is returned to the User:  `Sorry you are not allowed to create new data.`

The user will stay on the same page and the only thing that will happen is the pop up.

How do I do this without using JavaScript?

Thanks

Comment: It needs to be a popup? You can just display a message in plain html, then you don't need JavaScript.

Comment: If you want to control which features certain users have access to, I suggest you take a look at the Spring Security plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-core

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the create method is not allowed, why not just remove the create() method from the controller, delete the create.gsp page and remove the 'New' button from the list page?

If you do want to offer a 'New' button and display a popup message that says you can't use the button, that is probably easiest done in javascript.

If you can just display the message in the default grails message panel rather than in a popup, then change the controller method to

```
def create() {
    flash.message = "Sorry you are not allowed to create new data."
    redirect(action: "list")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prior to sending the user to the GSP view, you should make a decision in the controller, if the user is allowed to execute the create action. In your controller this could be something simple like:

```groovy
params.allowed = false
```

The result of this decision is then passed to you GSP where you can evaluate it inside the GSP using something like:

```
<g:if test="${params.allowed == false}"> 
Alert: you are not allowed...
</g:if>
```

For the alerts, there are good looking alternatives to javascript like: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts